# js: hiding divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am pretty new to Javascript so please bear with me.

```
$('#bioContent').css('display','none');
$('#skillsContent').css('display','none');
$('#credsTab').css('background-color','#fff');
$('#credsTab a').css('color','#19d700');
$('#bioTab').css('background-color','#ccc');
$('#bioTab a').css('color','#444');  
$('#skillsTab').css('background-color','#ccc');
$('#skillsTab a').css('color','#444');

$('#credsTab').click(function(){
  $('#credsContent').css('display','block');
  $('#bioContent').css('display','none');
  $('#skillsContent').css('display','none');
  $('#credsTab').css('background-color','#fff');
  $('#credsTab a').css('color','#19d700');
  $('#bioTab').css('background-color','#ccc');
  $('#bioTab a').css('color','#444');
  $('#skillsTab').css('background-color','#ccc');
  $('#skillsTab a').css('color','#444');
})

$('#bioTab').click(function(){
  $('#bioContent').css('display','block');
  $('#credsContent').css('display','none');
  $('#skillsContent').css('display','none');
  $('#bioTab').css('background-color','#fff');
  $('#bioTab a').css('color','#19d700');
  $('#credsTab').css('background-color','#ccc');
  $('#credsTab a').css('color','#444');
  $('#skillsTab').css('background-color','#ccc');
  $('#skillsTab a').css('color','#444');
})


$('#skillsTab').click(function(){
  $('#skillsContent').css('display','block');
  $('#bioContent').css('display','none');
  $('#credsContent').css('display','none');
  $('#skillsTab').css('background-color','#fff');
  $('#skillsTab a').css('color','#19d700');
  $('#bioTab').css('background-color','#ccc');
  $('#bioTab a').css('color','#444');
  $('#credsTab').css('background-color','#ccc');
  $('#credsTab a').css('color','#444');
})
```

That's my javascript implementation of tabs. Basically on click, divs hide away and others appear.

My problem with this is that on the skillsTab, there's an add skills method, and when I click on that, it refreshes the page, and when it does, it brings me back to the credsTab, the default when the page is loaded.

I was wondering if that's a way so that when it refreshes, it will stay on the skillsTab.

Comment: Just a tip, instead of doing `$('#bioContent').css('display','none');
` use $.hide and $.show like ``$("#bioContent").hide();`

Comment: *"bare* with me" No thanks. I hope you meant *"bear* with me" ;o)

Comment: i think he meant "bare with me" as in "hide/show css with me"

Comment: @kjy112: I'll accept just about any alternate interpretation to that which is seemingly implied.

Comment: Not too surprisingly, this has been [discussed at english.stackexchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/is-it-bear-or-bare-with-me).

Comment: Did anyone else cringe when they saw the wall of unchained identical `$.css` calls? Why weren't `addClass` and `removeClass` used?!?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/zfHHK/15/ Neatened your code up a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep state around, which can be done via [fragment URLs](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Unique_URLs) or [HTML5 history](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html).

e.g., make opening up the `skills` tab change the fragment to `#skills`, which will remain across a refresh.  Then check `window.location.hash` in your `onLoad` to determine what initial state your page should be in.

---

```
function switchToTab(tabName) {
    // DOM/CSS manipulation etc. here
}

var tabs = ['bio', 'skills', 'creds'];
var initialTab = 'bio';
for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    (function(tabName) {
        document.getElementById(tabName + 'Tab').addEventListener('click', function() {
            switchToTab(tabName);
            location.hash = '#' + tabName;
        }, false);
    })(tabs[i]);
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if (location.hash[0] == '#')
        switchToTab(location.hash.substr(1));
}, false);
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {
    if (location.hash[0] == '#')
        switchToTab(location.hash.substr(1));
    else
        switchToTab(initialTab);
}, false);
```

Untested, and there's plenty of JS libraries out there that abstract this away for you.

Comment: can you elaborate? I am very new.

Comment: it seems that on click it only switches to the last element of the array and not the others. whys that?

Comment: thanks, I am running rails though...how can I redirect to the path with the location hash?

Answer (score 1):

An initial suggestion. give all your tabs the same class, maybe `class='toggleableTab'` then you can use

```
$('.togglableTab').live('click',function(){
   $('.togglableTab').not(this).hide();
   $(this).show();

});
```

as for the page refresh. Look into using AJAX to "add" your skills live on the page without a full page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tabbed solutions already in place that you could make use of - for example, http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/. JQuery UI is a great way to have a lot of this work done for you.

If you want to do it yourself, I would also suggest a solution using classes, but slightly different than other suggestions. Instead, have two classes, "activeTab" and "tabbable". In your css, define "activeTab" as visible, and "tabbable" as hidden. Give each tab an ID and the class of "tabbable". Have a hidden field in your form called "activeTabId". Make sure that this gets passed back from the server side when you load the page, including setting it to the default tab when you first load the page. You could then run the following code on page load to make it all play well together:

```
$(".tabbable").click(new function(){
    $(".tabbable").removeClass("activeTab");
    $(this).addClass("activeTab");
    $("#activeTabId").val($(this).attr("id"));
});

$("#" + $("#activeTabId").val()).addClass("activeTab");
```